# Is there any nugets for parsing account and routing numbers?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using xamarin and looking to parse checks for customers on the device. I need to pull the number at the bottom of a check and parse the account and routing numbers. I cannot find a good library for this, do any exist?

Needs:

- Works in xamarin
- No internet connection
- Extracts and parses the account and routing numbers

Comment: Are you looking for something available at no cost or is there a specific budget you're wanting to adhere to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leadtools has NuGet packages for Xamarin for reading MICR text from checks. ([www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/micr](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/micr)). We support both MICR text recognition, as well as parsing the routing number, account number, and other information from the recognized text string. We even have a demo created specifically for reading checks in our "sample projects for Xamarin" package (LEADTOOLS Xamarin Projects 21\Examples\MicrDemo). As a disclaimer, I work for this vendor.

Here’s the minimal code you should need to recognize the text and parse the values:

```
using (RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs()){
    IOcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
    ocrEngine.Startup(codecs, null, null, null);

    BankCheckReader micrReader = new BankCheckReader();
    micrReader.OcrEngine = ocrEngine;

    micrReader.MicrFontType = BankCheckMicrFontType.E13b;
    using (RasterImage image = codecs.Load(filename)
        micrReader.ProcessImage(image);

    foreach (var value in micrReader.Results){
        if (value.Key != "Signature")
            Console.WriteLine($"{value.Key}: {value.Value.Text}\n");
    }
    ocrEngine.Shutdown();
}
```

[image: MICR demo screenshot]